# Translate WooCommerce products sorting options

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

I am trying to translate Woocommerce product sorting to the language of my country from the original english version.

Unfortunately it is working only partly, the text "Sort by" just can not be translated.

What I consider as a best option, I decided to edit the text using `functions.php` file in my Avada theme.

As I mentioned, there is only a part of a working code even if I use the same method (you can find it below).

```
function woosuite_change_cart_totals_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ( $text === 'Default Order' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Výchozí';
    }
    if ( $text === 'Name' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Jméno';
    }
    if ( $text === 'Popularity' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Oblíbené';
    }
    if ( $text === 'Sort by ' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Řadit dle ';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'woosuite_change_cart_totals_text', 20, 3 );
```

What is translated after this is visible in this screenshot.[image: SCREENSHOT] The text "Sort by " contains a space but I was trying to change without and still not working. It will translate everything without text "Sort by ".

Another attempt what I tried is also below (also not working):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'wc_customize_product_sorting');

function wc_customize_product_sorting($sorting_options){
    $sorting_options = array(
        'menu_order' => __( 'Řazení', 'woocommerce' ),
        'popularity' => __( 'Oblíbenost', 'woocommerce' ),
        'price'      => __( 'Cena: od nejnižší', 'woocommerce' ),
        'price-desc' => __( 'Cena: od nejvyšší', 'woocommerce' ),
    );

    return $sorting_options;
}
```

The same case is with the numbered of shown products (pagination).

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3):

To translate the sorting options, you can use one of the following code replacement instead:

```php
function translate_catalog_orderby_strings2( $orderby ) {
    if ( isset($orderby['menu_order']) ) {
        $orderby['menu_order'] = 'Výchozí řazení'; // 'Default sorting'
    }
    if ( isset($orderby['popularity']) ) {
        $orderby['popularity'] = 'Řadit dle oblíbené'; // 'Sort by popularity'
    }
    if ( isset($orderby['rating']) ) {
        $orderby['rating']     = 'Řadit dle průměrné hodnocení'; // 'Sort by average rating'
    }
    if ( isset($orderby['date']) ) {
        $orderby['date']       = 'Řadit dle nejnovější'; // 'Sort by latest'
    }
    if ( isset($orderby['price']) ) {
        $orderby['price']      = 'Řadit dle cena: nízká až vysoká'; // 'Sort by price: low to high'
    }
    if ( isset($orderby['price-desc']) ) {
        $orderby['price-desc'] = 'Řadit dle cena: vysoká až nízká'; // 'Sort by price: high to low'
    }
    return $orderby;
}
```

Or also:

```php
add_filter( 'gettext', 'translate_catalog_orderby_strings', 10, 3 );
function translate_catalog_orderby_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $translated_text;
    }
    if ( $text === 'Default sorting' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Výchozí řazení';
    } 
    elseif ( $text === 'Sort by popularity' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Řadit dle oblíbené';
    } 
    elseif ( $text === 'Sort by average rating' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Řadit dle průměrné hodnocení';
    } 
    elseif ( $text === 'Sort by latest' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Řadit dle nejnovější';
    } 
    elseif ( $text === 'Sort by price: low to high' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Řadit dle cena: nízká až vysoká';
    } 
    elseif ( $text === 'Sort by price: high to low' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Řadit dle cena: vysoká až nízká';
    } 
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: I found quite similar code in different places so I suppose it should works but unfortunately it is not working in my case. 

The first code you mentioned did not change anything ([screenshot](https://fram3d.cz/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/sorting.png)). 

The theme which I am using (Avada) has probably its own sorting not working with this code.

The second option will works only for the second part of the sorting -> only if I use the text without "Sort by" -> it will translate the text. If I will use the whole text instead, it will not change anything.

Thank you!

Comment: Then you should search/ask in Avada support pages…